# Plot multiple sparkles by overlapping each other

Tags: r, plot, lattice

I use following code to make a plot with the first set of my values (here it is the number of crimes).

This is what I do have now:
[image: My sparkline with single set of data]

Here is the code I use to plot it:

```
library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra)
library(grid)
library(reshape)
library(RCurl)
dd <- read.csv(text = getURL("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/GeekOnAcid/da022affd36310c96cd4/raw/9c2ac2b033979fcf14a8d9b2e3e390a4bcc6f0e3/us_nr_of_crimes_1960_2014.csv"))
d <- melt(dd, id="Year")
names(d)[1] <- "time"
pdf("sparklines_lattice_multiple_ten.pdf", height=10, width=8)
xyplot(value~time | variable, d, xlab="", ylab="", strip=F, lwd=0.7, col=1, type="l", 
       layout=c(1,length(unique(d$variable))), between = list(y = 1),
       scales=list(y=list(at=NULL, relation="free"), x=list(fontfamily="serif")), 
       par.settings = list(axis.line = list(col = "transparent"),
                           layout.widths=list(right.padding=20, left.padding=-5)),
       panel = function(x, y, ...) {
         panel.xyplot(x, y, ...)
         pushViewport(viewport(xscale=current.viewport()$xscale-5, 
                               yscale=current.viewport()$yscale, clip="off"))
         panel.text(x=tail(x,n=1), y=tail(y,n=1), labels=levels(d$variable)[panel.number()], 
                    fontfamily="serif", pos=4)
         popViewport()
         panel.text(x=x[which.max(y)], y=max(y), labels=round(max(y),0), cex=0.8,
                    fontfamily="serif",adj=c(0.5,2.5))
         panel.text(x=x[which.min(y)], y=min(y), labels=round(min(y),0), cex=0.8,
                    fontfamily="serif",adj=c(0.5,-1.5))
         panel.text(x=tail(x,n=1), y=tail(y,n=1), labels=round(tail(y,n=1),0), cex=0.8,
                    fontfamily="serif", pos=4)
         panel.points(x[which.max(y)], max(y),  pch=16, cex=1)
         panel.points(x[which.min(y)], min(y),  pch=16, cex=1, col="red")})
dev.off()
```

What I need: to add an extra dimension (i.e., extra line) to each sparkline with the number of suspects per each type of crime (e.g., Vehicle.Theft, Larceny.Theft, etc.). In other words, *I also want to add extra line to each sparkline to compare the dynamics of (1) the number of crimes and (2) the number of suspect for each type of crime*.

To be clear: *I want to set up two lines for each sparkline*.

Just before you answer my question please be aware of:

1. `par(new=TRUE)` doesn't work: `Warning message: In par(new = TRUE) : calling par(new=TRUE) with no plot`. It just creates two separated pages in a PDF file with two different sparklines. I need the opposite result: *two sparklines on the same PDF page*.

Thank you very much for your efforts to help me (if you do so).

Comment: Interesting visualization, thanks for sharing. However, you might increase the chance of getting suggestions if you'd #1 minimize the code, #2 fill _i have another set of values"_ with more (concrete data) life, and #3 add two screenshots with status quo and desired output.

Comment: Yes I did a couple of changes.